# Unarchiving in Ansible

Tags: ansible, yaml

I need suggestion on how to unzip the below tar content via ansible:
Below is the code snippet:

```
- name: Store DB details
  shell: ls -larth "{{ swdowloc }}"/*tar.gz|grep -i edb_redhat|awk '{print $9}'
  register: db_software_details
- debug:
    var: db_software_details["stdout"]
- name: Extract the software files
  unarchive:
    src: db_software_details
    dest: "{{ swdowloc }}"
    remote_src: yes
```

When I am executing the playbook, it gives the error as below:

```
TASK [swdwnld : Directory creation for software] *****************************************************************************
ok: [10.174.131.27]

TASK [swdwnld : Store DB details] ********************************************************************************************
changed: [10.174.131.27]

TASK [swdwnld : debug] *******************************************************************************************************
ok: [10.174.131.27] => {
    "db_software_details[\"stdout\"]": "/root/EDB_AUTOMATION/edb_softwares/edb_redhat_rhel-7-x86_64.tar.gz"
}

TASK [swdwnld : Extract the software files] **********************************************************************************
fatal: [10.174.131.27]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Source 'db_software_details' does not exist"}

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************************
10.174.131.27              : ok=7    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
10.174.131.31              : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
10.174.131.36              : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
10.174.131.56              : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Can anyone please suggest how to unarchive this file.

Thanks,
Sandeep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- name: Store DB details
  shell: ls -larth "{{ swdowloc }}"/*tar.gz|grep -i edb_redhat|awk '{print $9}'
  register: _db_software_details
- debug:
    var: _db_software_details["stdout"]
- name: Extract the software files
  unarchive:
    src: "{{ _db_software_details.stdout }}"
    dest: "{{ swdowloc }}"
    remote_src: yes
```

I fix naming var convention, and vars itsefl.

Comment: Is this "_db_software_details" (underscore sign important to be given at beginning).

Comment: Nope, is naming convention, in large playbook with a lot of roles, (sorry for my english), is important to diffenciate var generated in task with other vars set in hosts,groups ...The main problem of your's code is you want to use db_software_details vars but you use db_software_details str value, for use var "{{ db_software_details }}".